# Ошибка в коде бота для телеграмм

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.Telebot("%57772436XPhWiST72блюр-токенаqBaUnsqU%")
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
if message.text == "Привет":
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет, чем я могу тебе помочь?")
```

Ошибка:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax (указано стрелочкой на `if`):

> ```
>     if message.text == "Привет":
>     ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Я не понимаю почему в ошибке синтаксиса указано на `if`, где ошибка, как исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка возникает потому, что

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
```

– это *[декоратор функции](https://tproger.ru/translations/demystifying-decorators-in-python/).*

И после декоратора ожидается *функция*, которую он декорирует, обычно ее определение начинающие ключевым словом `def`. Решительно не `if`.

---

*Как ваш код исправить:*

`@bot.message_handler` определяет фильтры, которые сообщение (message) должно выполнить. Когда их оно выполняет, **декорированная функция** *вызывается* (причем принятое сообщение ее передано как ее аргумент).

Значит, вам нужно **создать функцию с одним аргументом**, которая будет выполнять ваш код:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.Telebot("%57772436XPhWiST72блюр-токенаqBaUnsqU%")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def some_name(message):
    if message.text == "Привет":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет, чем я могу тебе помочь?")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if message.text == "Привет":
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет, чем я могу тебе помочь?")
```

Данный код надо запихнуть в функцию. Выглядеть должно так:

```
def sms(message):
    if message.text == "Привет":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет, чем я могу тебе помочь?")
```

И так для любого действия по типу сохранения фотографии от пользователя надо создавать отдельную функцию